# docker build failed with [webpack-cli] Failed to load webpack.prod.js

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, webpack-5

> [webpack-cli] Error: Cannot find module '/opt/finastra/app/webpack.prod.js'

webpack.common.js

[image]

webpack.dev.js

[image]

webpack.prod.js

[image]

```
depndencies:{
  "webpack": "^5.75.0",
   "webpack-cli": "^5.0.1"
}

"prod": "webpack --mode production --config webpack.prod.js",
```

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code, errors or other text. Copy the original text to your question and format properly